# ddslick set Max height

Tags: jquery, css

My code is like this

```
 $jq('#<portlet:namespace/>PNLanguage'+ languageId).ddslick({      
                       data : parsedLanguageData,
                       width:200,
                       Height:300,
                       selectText: "Select Language",
```

Which is working fine. But when we select the value and go for another dropdown, it is showing the empty space if the list size is less than the height.

When I change the value of height parameter to max-height=300 then works fine. How to give this in ddslick in above code.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for max-height in ddslick, but if you remove the height option from the JS file and edit the JS file roughly line 47 to change the class dd-options to include max-height:300px; then it will work exactly as required:

```
'.dd-options{ max-height:300px; border:solid 1px #ccc; border-top:none; list-style:none; box-shadow:0px 1px 5px #ddd; display:none; position:absolute; z-index:2000; margin:0; padding:0;background:#fff; overflow:auto;}' +
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a height option so it will work with newer versions.  Note that you should supply lower case height, not with a capital H.  Also note that you could view all options by observing / changing the defaults in the js file:

```
//Set defauls for the control
defaults = {
    data: [],
    keepJSONItemsOnTop: false,
    width: 260,
    height: 300,   // i changed this from null!
    background: "#eee",
    selectText: "",
    defaultSelectedIndex: null,
    truncateDescription: true,
    imagePosition: "left",
    showSelectedHTML: true,
    clickOffToClose: true,
    onSelected: function () { }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I've passed maxHeight to the constructor by using parameter "**maxHeight**" **not** "**max-height**" [Note: It gives error while passing "**max-height**"].

Then, this parameter is collected in the two variables- "l" and "arguments". This "arguments" variable is passed to init() method.

Now, inside init() method, you can set max height as below:

```
u.css({
    width : l.width
    ,'max-height': l.maxHeight
});
```